# Organizar cuadricula Boostrap HTML, CSS

Tags: html, bootstrap

Cordial Saludo, les muestro lo que tengo hecho con boostrap
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso me muestra una x cantidad de productos de esa forma en vista escritorio,

cuando pasa a vista celular es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo funciona bien, lo que quiero es que cuando sea vista celular, no se vea 1 solo producto en toda la pantalla si no 2.

Este es el contenedor principal:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <div id="scroll_3">
                        <div id="DATOS_PRODUCTOS"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

Y este el contenedor de cada producto:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">

                            <img src="<?php echo $RUTA_IMAGEN; ?>" alt="" style="width: 100%;height:250px;">

                </div>
```

Para el ejemplo con que organice las img es suficiente.

Quedo atento

Comment: Version de Bootstrap?

Comment: @MatíasRodríguez Bootstrap v3.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar `col-xs-6` a cada producto (xs es tamaño celular). Ten en cuenta que esto te servirá hasta la versión 3.x, ya que luego se quitó y sm pasó a ser el tamaño más pequeño, por lo que si actualizas el bootstrap tendrás que cambiarlo por `col-sm-6` y a `col-sm-3` por `col-md-3`

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

    <img src="<?php echo $RUTA_IMAGEN; ?>" alt="" style="width: 100%;height:250px;">

  </div>
```

Comment: Gracias, ya me funcionó

Comment: En realidad no es necesario el cambio que mencionas según la versión. Lo que puedes usar es la clase `.col-x` sin un _breakpoint_ definido. Quedaría entonces cada columna de la siguiente manera: `<div class="col-6 col-sm-3">Imagen</div>`, esto funciona desde la versión 3.x en adelante

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta!